# Org-mode export: force page break after TOC

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm using org-mode to export to PDF. I'm going over the same document multiple times and exporting different branches during my evaluation.

I always want the first section in the PDF to start on a clean page, regardless of which subtree I export. So, there should always be a `cleanpage` after the TOC.

I can manually add `newpage` everywhere in my org-mode doc, but I have a tree with thousands of branches. I'd rather add this in the latex preamble or `.emacs` config, once.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the following to your init file:

```
(setq org-latex-toc-command "\\tableofcontents \\clearpage")
```

Explanation: 
The variable `org-latex-toc-command` normally is set to the value `"\\tableofcontents"` and  its value is emitted by the LaTeX exporter into the output TeX file at the place where the TOC is to be placed (normally right after the `\begin{document}` in the TeX file):

```
 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 ...
```

When the TeX file is processed to produce the PDF output file, the LaTeX processor expands the `\tablecontents` macro to the full TOC.

By modifying the value of `org-latex-toc-command`, the LaTeX exporter is made to emit the modified string, so the TeX file looks liks this:

```
 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents \clearpage
 ...
```

When the modified TeX file is processed by the LaTeX processor, after `\tableofcontents` is expanded to the full TOC, the `\clearpage` macro causes the page to be emitted immediately, leaving the rest of it blank.

Note BTW, that in an emacs string like `"\\foo"`, the first backslash "escapes" the second, so that *one* backslash is part of the string. More about such escape sequences can be found in the Emacs documentation, e.g. [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Syntax.html#index-string-syntax-4815) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Char-Syntax.html#index-escape-sequence-75).

Comment: You might show the doc of that variable and make clear what that value does. That might be more helpful.

Comment: @Drew: Edited, PTAL.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to permanently change the value of `org-latex-toc-command` (as per @NickD answer), you can also include a latex export block before the first section

```
#+begin_export latex
  \clearpage \tableofcontents \clearpage
#+end_export

* Fist section
```

Remember to include `#+OPTIONS: toc:nil` in the preamble to avoid a double TOC

Comment: This can also be done with file variables.  Put this as the first line: `#+COMMENT:-*- org-latex-toc-command: "\\tableofcontents \\clearpage" -*-`. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html

Comment: `@@latex:\clearpage@@` before main text should work as well. Also, it doesn't need `#+OPTIONS: toc:nil`.

Answer (score 3):

I have been in need to add `\clearpage` at certain places of my document to format the output in a detailed way.

Add `#+latex: \clearpage` above or under any heading to break the page at this point.

Hope this helps!